# Calculate average time using 2 columns from separate MySQL Tables

Tags: mysql, database, average

I have two separate tables with identical column names like so:

t1:

```
request_submit_time | request_complete_time
2017-04-12 13:20:23 | 2017-04-12 13:21:23
2017-04-12 13:15:54 | 2017-04-13 13:10:54
```

t2:

```
request_submit_time | request_complete_time
2017-04-13 13:21:23 | 2017-04-15 13:30:23
2017-04-14 13:15:54 | 2017-04-15 13:09:54
```

I know how to get the average of the times from a single table using:

```
SELECT AVG(timestampdiff(HOUR,request_submit_time,request_complete_time)) AS average FROM tbl1;
```

but I cannot figure out how to get the average time between the 2 columns across the 2 tables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use UNION ALL to join the result sets from both tables then calculate: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/union.html

```
SELECT AVG(timestampdiff(HOUR,request_submit_time,request_complete_time)) AS 
average FROM
(
    (SELECT request_submit_time, request_complete_time FROM tbl1)
    UNION ALL
    (SELECT request_submit_time, request_complete_time FROM tbl2)
)
```

**Edit** - mpen is correct. You must use UNION ALL as UNION will remove duplicates. Thank you mpen.

Comment: I think you want `UNION ALL`. `UNION` will dedupe which will throw off the average.

Comment: Thanks! That worked except for having to move "AS average" to the end of the query or else I get a "Every derived table must have its own alias" error.